# The atom packages doesn't want to install

Tags: package, installation, atom-editor

The install buttoon turns blue striped but nothing happens and after a while it turns back to light blue. I checked under installed packages but it wasn't there. I googled which showed maybe it was the anti-virus but I temporarily disabled it. Any ideas what to do next?[image: Here you can see how the install button looks, but I think it is supposed to look that way]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Patience. Sometimes you should just wait.